How to force scrolling down in a browser page using Microsoft.XMLHTTP?
With this code I can go to this webpage and capture the first 10 events.  The problem is that there are 30+ events and I need to capture them all.  When you are scrolling manually with the mouse something triggers the retrieval of the next 10 events.  How do I do this programmatically in VBA until I get to the bottom?
Sub DownloadFile()
Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Dim oStream As Object
Dim myURL As String
Dim LocalFilePath As String

    myURL = "https://www.meetup.com/cflfreethought/events/"
    LocalFilePath = "C:\Users\Brooks\Desktop\HTML_download.txt"
    
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "", ""  '("username", "password")
    WinHttpReq.send
    
    If WinHttpReq.status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile LocalFilePath, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
    End If

End Sub


The thing with Microsoft.XMLHTTP is that it's not a browser, it's mainly a library that allows you to send HTTP requests and get the response, but it doesn't render the HTML page and doesn't execute any JavaScript code on the client-side.
If you need to scroll the page and trigger Javascript code to load more results, you'll need to use a browser. There are a few ways to do that with VBA, but the most common approach is to use a VBA wrapper around the popular Selenium Library.
Regarding which wrapper to choose, the most popular remains SeleniumBasic. There is even a video tutorial to help you get started using Chrome.
However, SeleniumBasic hasn't received an update in a while and it no longer works with FireFox. If you need to use FireFox or want to use a more recent project, you can also have a look at SeleniumVBA  or TinySeleniumVBA.
EDIT:
It seems that the tutorial I linked above is outdated with regards to the download of the Chrome Driver.
To download the latest Chrome driver, you'll need to visit this page:
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/
Look at the Stable section for the rows starting with ChromeDriver and download the appropriate version for your machine (mine is Windows 64bit):

If you need an older version of the Chrome driver, you'll need to find the corresponding URL in the following JSON file:
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json

See also: How can I scroll down a webpage using Selenium with VBA

I installed SeleniumBasic but I get a can't find chrome binary error when I try to run a test script.  But I can see chrome.exe in a folder.

@Brooks, have you installed the latest Chrome Driver like shown in the video tutorial? I've also edited my answer to give updated instructions regarding how to download it.

I downloaded https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/127.0.6533.88/win64/chrome-win64.zip and tried running it.  I get warnings about running the setup.exe, but i give permission and it still won't run.  Not sure why?

@Brooks, you downloaded the binaries for "chrome" instead of the "chromedriver". Look at the screenshot and the big red rectangle in my answer.

Once you have downloaded the driver, you need to put it in the SeleniumBasic folder as explained in the video tutorial.

I do have both chrome.exe and chromedrive.exe on my PC.  "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" and "C:\Users\Brooks\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\chromedriver.exe".

Use the new Edge Browser Control of Access.
Mike Wolfe has published an extended list of resources, tutorials, etc.:
Resources for the Modern Edge-Based Browser Control in Microsoft Access
That should get you started.

Thanks.  I created a form with the Edge Browser control on it, but can't find a property or action that will return the html/data from the webpage.

I made some progress with this yesterday.  Thanks.

If you found a solution, please post it as an answer.

Having some success with this:Dim browserControl As Object
Dim browserControl As Object
Dim htmlContent As String
Set browserControl = Me.EdgeBrowser1

' Navigate to the desired webpage
'browserControl.Navigate "https://www.example.com"

' Wait for the page to load completely

Do While browserControl.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

' Retrieve the entire HTML content of the page
htmlContent = browserControl.RetrieveJavascriptValue("document.documentElement.outerHTML")


I can retrieve the data that is initially loaded with the webpage.  The problem is that additional data is loaded dynamically.  Manually, it happens when a user scrolls down.  I've tried to do that programmatically without success.  Any additional help would be appreciated.  Me!EdgeBrowser1.ExecuteJavascript "window.scrollBy(0, 5000);"
Me!EdgeBrowser1.ExecuteJavascript "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);"  - these don't work.
